# Url routing in Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, url-routing, codeigniter-2

I have url like `http://example.com/blog/viewpost/1` and i want to change the url like `http://example.com/1`. I am using codeigniter 2.x framework so i have changed the routes.php like,

```
$route['default_controller'] = "blog";
$route['/(:num)'] = 'blog/viewpost/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

My controller blog.php,

```
public function viewpost($id)
    {

        $view['text'] = $this->blog_model->get_post_by_id($id);
        $view['maincategory'] = $this->blog_model->get_main_category();
        foreach ($view['text'] as $text){
            # code...
            $count = $text->views;
            $count = $count+1;
            $this->blog_model->popular_view($id,$count);   
        }
        $this->load->view('readmore',$view);
    }
```

when i executing the program, the url is not changing. I have done lots of projects in codeigniter framework but I've never done the url routing before. So i hope someone will help on this issue.

Comment: what do you mean by **the url is not changing**? Do you except url `http://example.com/1` will automatically changed to `http://example.com/blog/viewpost/1`? Or just want to display the content of `http://example.com/blog/viewpost/1`?

Comment: I want to change my actual url like `http://example.com/1`.. And my actual url is `http://example.com/blog/viewpost/1` @Chayan

Comment: Routing will not give any visible effect in `url` structure. It treat `http://example.com/1` url as `http://example.com/blog/viewpost/1` and give you the outputs. So you need `redirection` of your `url`.

Comment: Thanks @Chayan I understand the routing..

Answer (score 1):

You can route like `$route['{default_controller}/{default_method}/(:num)'] = "{original_controller}/{original_method}/$1";` in the file '{root}/system/application/config/routes.php'. For more you can visit http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-routes-tutorial

=======================

Add the below code on your "Blog" controller.

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array()) {
    if ($method == 'viewpost') {
        $this->$method($params[0]);
    } else {
        $this->default_method();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Astro First remove `$route['/(:num)'] = 'blog/viewpost/$1';` from "routes.php". And then add the code like i updated my answer, check it.

Comment: The code is fine. But i found out the issue which is in url redirection. Actually i have misunderstood the url routing. Now i am understand through the @Chayan comment.